# How to add a column constraint in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in MS Sql 2008 r2, I would like add a constrain to a column with I can accept only 3 value like

```
myColum      char(2)    constrain values (A1, B2, C3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
myColum  char(2)  check (myColum in ('A1', 'B2', 'C3'))
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e304

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `SQL CHECK Constraint` supported by sql server .

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    myColum       char(2) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT chk_Person CHECK (myColum in ('A1', 'B2', 'C3')) 
)
```

Comment: +1, I always prefer to specify a meaningful name because the system generated default names are junk.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE <table>
ADD CHECK col in ('A1', 'B2', 'C3')
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT ck_y CHECK (myColum in ('A1','B2','C3'))
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE
(
 myColumn char(2) NOT NULL check(myColumn= 'A1' or myColumn= 'B2'  myColumn= 'C3') 
)
```